# Writing Unit Test for saving the model

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I am a grails beginner.. and learing to write unit test case

I have 2-domain

```
class Employee {

    String name
    String department

    static hasOne =[address: Address]   


    public String toString() {
        name
    }
}
```

---

```
class Address {

    String line1
    String line2

    Employee employee

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

so here is my AddressControllerTest.groovy

```
 void testSave() {

        def address = new Address(line1: "Kaser Road", line2: "Bridage Town")
        .addToEmployee(new Employee(name: "monda", department:"IT")).save()

        controller.save()

        assert model.addressInstance != null
}
```

which gives an error report

```
No signature of method: trip.side.Address.addToEmployee() is applicable for argument types: (trip.side.Employee) values: [monda] Possible solutions: setEmployee(trip.side.Employee), getEmployee()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: trip.side.Address.addToEmployee() is applicable for argument types: (trip.side.Employee) values: [monda]
Possible solutions: setEmployee(trip.side.Employee), getEmployee()
    at trip.side.AddressControllerTests.testSave(AddressControllerTests.groovy:41)
```

can anyone suggest me the correct way of doing it .

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Grails, which domain classes, you want to mock, so use:

```
mockDomain( Employee )
mockDomain( Address )
```

This is related to Grails 1.x, version 2.x uses annotations:

```
@Mock( [ Employee, Address ] )
```

Comment: I think the syntax would be    `@Mock([Employee,Address])`

Answer (score 1):

While you still need to do the mocking as Tom said, you are using `addTo*` incorrectly - that is exactly what the error message is telling you.  `addTo*` is used for one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, NOT one-to-one relationships.  You would do something like this the way you have your domains set up:

```
def employee = new Employee(name: "monda", department:"IT", address: new Address(line1: "Kaser Road", line2: "Bridage Town")).save()
```